# VK API group.getMembers: В ответе меньше данных, чем запрашивалось

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, settimeout, jsonp

Всем привет. Использую в своем приложении VK API, чтобы получить пользователей указанных групп. Использую, соответственно метод groups.getMembers.

Все бы хорошо, но в ответе приходят меньше данных. Например, в запросе указан count=800, а приходит только 650 пользователей. Только на первом запросе в цепочке приходит сколько надо (т.к. юзеров много, то разбиваю все на несколько запросов), а в остальных меньше. В итоге получается заметная недостача.

Запросы делаются по таймауту, т.е. отложенно.

Вот код:

```
var DELAY_PER_REQUEST = 600;
var COUNT = 800;
var OFFSET_STEP = COUNT;    
var callbackRegistry = {};  
var requiredDelay = 0;
var membersDataCollection = {
    count: 0,
    users: []
};

...

// Выполнить запрос
function execRequest(method, params, callback){
    var url = VK_URL + method + '?';
    for (var param in params){
        url += param + '=' + params[param] + '&';
    }

    var callbackName = generateCallbackName();
    url += 'callback=RequestManager.callbackRegistry.' + callbackName;

    callbackRegistry[callbackName] = function(data) {
        scriptOk = true;
        delete callbackRegistry[callbackName];
        callback(data); 
        deleteRequestScript(callbackName);
    };

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = script.onerror = function(){
        if (scriptOk) return;
        delete callbackRegistry[callbackName];
    };
    script.src = url;
    script.setAttribute('data-callback', callbackName);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// Получить часть членов группы
function getPartMembers(groupId, params, callback, delay, offset, offsetStep){

    params.offset = offset;

    // Коллбек для сбора всех пользователей
    var requestCollectCallback = function(data){

        if (!data || !data.hasOwnProperty('response')) return;

        if (offset === 0){
            membersDataCollection.count = data.response.count;                              
        }

        console.log('Response users.len = ' + data.response.users.length);
        membersDataCollection.users = membersDataCollection.users.concat(data.response.users);
        var message = 'Идет загрузка пользователей сообщества {' + groupId + '}. Загружено ' +
            membersDataCollection.users.length + '/' + data.response.count + ' пользователей. Подождите пожалуйста.';
        $waitingMesage.text(message);           

        if ( (offset + offsetStep) >= data.response.count ) {               
            callback(membersDataCollection);                                
        }
    }

    if ( !delay ) {
        execRequest(GROUPS_METHODS.getMembers, params, requestCollectCallback);
        return;
    }

    setTimeout(function(){
        execRequest(GROUPS_METHODS.getMembers, params, requestCollectCallback);
    }, delay);
}

...

// Получить членов группы
    getMembers: function(groupId, membersCount, callback, delay, isLastGroup){          

        var params = { group_id: groupId, count: COUNT, fields: 'domain,photo_50' };
        var iterations = Math.ceil( membersCount / COUNT ); 
        console.log( 'Iterations', iterations );        

        membersDataCollection.count = 0;
        membersDataCollection.users = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
            getPartMembers( groupId, params, callback, ( delay + (DELAY_PER_REQUEST * i) ), (OFFSET_STEP * i), OFFSET_STEP );               
        }

        // обнулям счетчик задержки, чтобы на следующих сериях запросах небыло большой задержки
        requiredDelay += (iterations * DELAY_PER_REQUEST);
        if (isLastGroup) requiredDelay = 0;
    }
```

В итоге получается такой результат в консоли:

```
Iterations 5
bundle.js:96 Response users.len = 800
bundle.js:96 Response users.len = 572
bundle.js:96 Response users.len = 572
bundle.js:96 Response users.len = 572
bundle.js:96 Response users.len = 572
bundle.js:341 Object {count: 3772, users: Array[3088]}
```

Соответственно должно получаться по 800 чел в каждом запросе, но начиная со 2го все почему то меньше.

И, что интересно, если запускать вызовы без таймаута, то, в результате, приходят все пользователи.

Почему так происходит и как решить данную проблему? (Используя отложенные вызовы)

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил, отказавшись от создания таймаутов в цикле. Если вызывать один таймаут из другого, то все в порядке.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, решение проблемы будет полезно многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что вы используете один объект `params` для всех вызовов. Но внутри `getPartMembers()` вы делаете `params.offset = offset`, так что в конечном итоге `params.offset` оказывается равен последнему переданному `offset`, и именно с таким значением выполняются все отложенные вызовы.

Для решения проблемы достаточно каждый раз передавать новый объект `params`, т.е. в функции `getMembers()` внести

```
var params = { ... };
```

внутрь цикла `for`.